# my app is not running still in my phone but is not showing any error

Tags: android, runtime-error

It Shows no error on Android Studio but app even not starting on phone.Is there any problem with the code.I feel like there may be any mistakes in syntax but i am not able to find one.Please help me.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private Button bDriver,bCustomer;
   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button bDriver=(Button)findViewById(R.id.driver);
    Button bCustomer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.customer);
    bDriver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new 
                       Intent(MainActivity.this,DriverLoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

    });
    bCustomer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent ryt=new 
                  Intent(MainActivity.this,CustomerLoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(ryt);
            finish();

        }
    });
   }
  }
```

And activity_main.xml is this and please explain if there is any problem related to SDK version also upload the detail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.trillcore.uber.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/driver"
    android:layout_below="@+id/customer"
    android:text="I am a Driver"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I am a Customer"
    android:layout_above="@+id/driver"
    android:id="@+id/customer"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you building the apk and pass it to your phone? I advice you to connect the mobile via usb and run the app directly

Comment: Not enough information.  Can we see your activity_main.xml?

Comment: No i m using Debugger to directly run it .

Comment: Have you checked in the logcat, this will show any errors that are happening when the app launches